# What kind of granularity is recommended in reactive programming when publishing state change events?

Tags: event-programming, reactive, event-handling

I'm currently developing an application using reactive programming. Every entity creation or modification in the system publishes an event and no two entities can be created/modified within the same use case.

In this situation, there are entities that have to be created based on specific states of other entities. For example, there is an entity Slot that, when created with a state IN_AUCTION, should trigger the creation of an Auction entity. This is optional, as the Slot could be created with a state AVAILABLE, in which case, no Auction should be created.

Given this is the case, my doubt is about the type of event to publish when the Slot is created. These are the options I've thought about:

1. Publish a generic SlotCreatedEvent. In this case, the listener would need to verify the state of the Slot, either by adding it to the Slot event or by querying it to check its state.
2. Publish a SlotInAuctionEvent or a SlotAvailableEvent. In this case, there would be a specific listener that would create the Auction without checking the Slot state but if I follow this approach I could have an explosion of events.

So, given this example, what's the expected granularity when publishing events? Should there be a specific event for each state/entity modification or just a generic one with all the information of the entity modified?

Comment: 3.  Publish a `SlotInAuctionEvent` that only creates an auction if the required conditions exist?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the `SlotInAuctionEvent` indicates that the condition has been met. The question is if it is a good idea to have a separate event for every state in which a slot can be created vs. having one event that provides the data for the listeners to do the condition-checking.

Comment: Can a slot later change its state to IN_AUCTION and will that also trigger the creation of an auction?

Comment: @doubleYou: If you only create the slot and fire the event when conditions are correct, you won't have to do the check afterwards.  Hell, you might not even need the event.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so the `SlotFactory` checks the condition and then triggers (via event or otherwise) the creation of an auction? I think that's basically option 2 in that you need a separate event for each condition. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @doubleYou: Why do you need events to check conditions?  Wouldn't those conditions simply be a part of your business logic?

Comment: The idea is that the slot at creation can be in state available or in auction.once the auction is finished, if there is a winner it would change to reserved, otherwise it would change to available. Once in either of these states, it can keep changing to the other one but never again to in auction.but there is always a slot to be created and an event to publish as it is used to schedule the next slot to be created. A SlotCreatedEvent is enough to schedule the next one as it is always necessary but the creation of an Auction depends on the state

Comment: The conditions are part of the business logic but the business logic is split in use cases. Each use case needs to verify different conditions, one of them whether an Auction has to be created. The question is about whether the events should be granular enough to identify exactly what happen or generic.Specific events avoid certain checks in specific situations like going to database or ask a service for the state of something for example. Adding this information in the event would also avoid asking for the information somewhere else but then it may cause the events to contain too much info

Comment: `The question is about whether the events should be granular enough to identify exactly what happen or generic`  -- That would depend on what, precisely, your requirements are.  My concern is that the business logic that decides whether or not to create a `SlotFactory` appears to occur *outside* of the mechanism that creates the `SlotFactory` in the first place, which would suggest a degree of brittleness; you depend on those outside forces to do things correctly.

Comment: I didn't get that part about the SlotFactory. The slot is always created (using a SlotFactory) and that triggers an event. There is another part of the system that listens to it and reacts creating the associated Auction. To create this Auction,either the listener blindly creates it after receiving a specific SlotInAuctionEvent or checks the state of the Slot after receiving a SlotCreatedEvent. The question is whether the source of events should be granular enough to avoid other systems to do a check or if that's irrelevant and the source shouldn't care about possible listeners' needs

Comment: Are you looking for a "best practice?"  The best practice is the one that most effectively meets your specific needs.  Evaluate the pros and cons of each choice, and choose the one with the best pros and the least cons *in your specific context.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey Kind of. My motivation comes from trying to understand what a common approach is. In some situations it could show some problems in the design. Sometimes by just asking the question, one realises what is happening is just a missing step.

Comment: In any case, I think your particular decision is going to be driven by your specific circumstances and needs, not on what the "common" approach is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, I think what's most convenient for your event handlers should be a secondary concern. One of the major advantages of events is that the event source does not need to know anything about the consumers - so you don't know what their needs are.

The question really comes down to what constitutes an event conceptually. I would argue that creating an "in auction" slot and a "not in auction" slot are *not* separate events - otherwise, you end up with a separate event for every combination of parameters.

However, you'll also want to avoid flooding your consumers with unnecessary information. Furthermore, I think it's wise to avoid sending the same information in different events, if possible.

In your example, you risk duplicating the status information in the `SlotCreated` event and the `SlotStatusUpdated` event. If you had to react to a slot being 'available', you'd have to subscribe to two events.

A possible solution to this problem might be to publish two events when you create a slot: the `SlotCreated` event does not carry slot-status information, but you'll also immediately raise `SlotStatusUpdated`. Then `AuctionCreator` only has to subscribe to the latter. (If `SlotCreated` is of no interest to anyone, you could even skip this event).

Side Note: A module that only needs to react to *new* slots with a given status will have to do more work in this case. I'd argue that this is a natural reflection of the more complex condition. (If there are many such subscribers, you could have an intermediary that combines both events to a new event). In any case, there may be situations where this approach is not practical, but I do think it would usually be a relatively clean solution.

I think we can summarize the above considerations into the following *rules of thumb*:

- If two events hold the same information, extract that into a new event
- Don't create a new event just to suit a subscriber's needs

Unfortunately, this still leaves one question open: do we have a `StatusChanged` event or separate `SlotOpenedForAuction`, `SlotReserved` and `SlotMadeAvailable` events?

There might be a technical reason for choosing separate events: if you have a large number of subscribers, each of which only has to handle slots in a particular status, separate events are more efficient. (Raising an event is an O(n) operation). Otherwise, you should use the domain terminology as a guide - i.e. do users talk about a slot's 'status'?

Comment: As of now there aren't many use cases really. There is only the handler that schedules the next slot and the one that creates the auction. My concern is about the information to include in the events, if that is a symptom of a design problem.But thinking about it, maybe what I'm missing is a middle step.An auction also requires an end time which is based on a configuration stored on the entity that triggers the slot creation in the first place. So I think I can publish the event,listen to it in the module with the config and publish a CreateAuctionCommand.Would that make sense?

Comment: Is the `EndTime` a property of the `Slot` (conceptually speaking)? If so, I'd include it in an event. Otherwise, I'm not sure if the `SlotCreator` should be concerned with auctions (and their end times) at all - is there a reason the `AuctionCreator` can't hold that configuration? In your suggestion, it seems the `SlotCreator` is responsible for creating both `Slot`s and `Auction`s.

Comment: The `Slot` has an end time of its own. The `Auction` end time is defined in the configuration of the `Room` entity, that is who triggers the `Slot` creation in the first place. That's why I suggested listening to the `SlotCreatedEvent` so the `Room` can react to it by triggering the `CreateAuctionCommand` that would include the `slotId` and the `Auction` configuration.

Comment: Okay so (correct me if I'm wrong): `SlotCreator` creates a event with an expiration time (which should be part of the event). In response to that event, `AuctionCreator` creates an auction with its own end time, based on some config that `AuctionCreator` holds, and possibly the expiration time of the `SlotCreatedEvent`. So far so good. Now `SlotCreator` and `AuctionCreator` are actually both implemented in `Room`. That may be totally fine, or it may put completely separate responsibilities into `Room` - I can't decide that without knowing the rest of the system.

Comment: `Room`, `Slot` and `Auction` are all completely separated. Each one only publishes events of itself and there are listeners reacting to them. Each listener calls a use case that contains references to components that handle each type of entity. In terms of DDD, currently each one is its own aggregate and I haven't found a reason to include any within another one. Use cases would be the domain services. `Room` contains config for each `Slot` and the `Auction` associated so, for me, a use case should call `Room` for each event published by `Slot` and `Auction` and let it decide next action

Comment: The implementation tries to follow my understanding of books `Clean Architecture` and `Software Architecture for developers`.There is an interface named after each component (`RoomComponent` for example) which hides all implementation related to an entity so there is no way to handle a `Slot` within the `RoomComponent` for example.Use cases are the ones synchronising them (asking one for info to modify another one for example) and I'm trying to avoid modifying more than one component per use case to avoid the usage of transactions.I hope it makes sense,I could modify the entry to add details.